# EF5 And cycles or multiple cascade paths, FOREIGN KEY

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I got a wierd problem, i already know about why normaly this exception happen and how to solve it by Disablaing WillCascadeOnDelete to False in one of the properties.

But my problem seems to be other kind,
Here is my code :

Memeber :

```
 public class Memeber
       {
      public int MemberID { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Message> RecievedMessages { get; set; }
       }

    public class Message
    {
      public long MessageID { get; set; }
      public int SenderMemberId{ get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Member> RecipientsMembers { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("SenderMemberId")]
      public virtual Member SenderMember { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the mapping :
 in Message configuration:

```
    this.HasRequired(c => c.SenderMember)
            .WithMany(c => c.SentMessages)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderMemberId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and in MemberConfiguration :

```
 this.HasMany(c => c.RecievedMessages)
        .WithMany(c => c.RecipientsMembers)

        .Map(cm =>
        {
            cm.ToTable("MessageJoinMemeber");
            cm.MapLeftKey("MessageId");
            cm.MapRightKey("MemberId");

        });
```

As you see a message  hase a sender with ForeignKey SenderID, one to many bidirrectional.
and Member has 2 list of messages one as reciever and one list as sender.
I tried to disableing cascading on delete in one of those relation(first one)
but i still get the same problem from SQL engine.
Also i tried to  define the relation from Message part and not from member part
 with :

```
        this.HasMany(c => c.RecipientsMembers)
               .WithMany(c=> c.RecievedMessages)
               .Map ( cm =>
                {
                cm.ToTable("MessageJoinMemeber");
                cm.MapLeftKey("MessageId");
                cm.MapRightKey("MemberId");

                });
```

But Allways i get this Error :

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.MessageJoinMemeber_dbo.Messages_MemberId' on table 'MessageJoinMemeber' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=16
  LineNumber=1
  Number=1785
  Procedure=""
  Server=KINGPC
  State=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine (it's the **same** as what you have)

```
public class Member
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> RecievedMessages { get; set; }
}
public class Message
{
    public long MessageID { get; set; }
    public int SenderMemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> RecipientsMembers { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SenderMemberId")]
    public virtual Member SenderMember { get; set; }
}
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.SenderMember)
    .WithMany(c => c.SentMessages)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderMemberId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
    .HasMany(c => c.RecievedMessages)
    .WithMany(c => c.RecipientsMembers)
    .Map(cm =>
    {
        cm.ToTable("MessageJoinMemeber");
        cm.MapLeftKey("MessageId");
        cm.MapRightKey("MemberId");

    });
...
var member = new Member { Name = "sender1"  };
db.Messages.Add(new Message
{
    SenderMember = new Member { Name = "sender1" },
    RecipientsMembers = new List<Member> 
    {
        new Member { Name = "receiver1"  },
        new Member { Name = "receiver2"  },
        new Member { Name = "receiver3"  },
    }
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

...but if you still have problems you can make the join table manually...

```
// public virtual ICollection<Message> RecievedMessages { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MessageJoinMember> Recieved { get; set; }
...
// public virtual ICollection<Member> RecipientsMembers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MessageJoinMember> Recipients { get; set; }
...
public class MessageJoinMember
{
    public long MessageID { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.SenderMember)
    .WithMany(c => c.SentMessages)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SenderMemberId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageJoinMember>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.MessageID, x.MemberID });
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageJoinMember>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Message)
    .WithMany(x => x.Recipients)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MessageID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageJoinMember>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Member)
    .WithMany(x => x.Recieved)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
// remove the implicit many-to-many here
...
var message = new Message { SenderMember = new Member { Name = "sender1" }, };
db.MessageJoinMembers.Add(new MessageJoinMember { Message = message, Member = new Member { Name = "receiver1" } });
db.MessageJoinMembers.Add(new MessageJoinMember { Message = message, Member = new Member { Name = "receiver2" } });
db.MessageJoinMembers.Add(new MessageJoinMember { Message = message, Member = new Member { Name = "receiver3" } });
db.Messages.Add(message);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: And shall i need to add this MessagejoinMembers to my DbContext?

Comment: Not needed as far as this model goes (that you gave me here). Both work - and this works just fine (the above part - e.g. `solution `) - and I don't see any issues w/ it, it's exact same thing I used in couple places. If you have some errors - then it's something else giving you errors.

Comment: But, I gave you the second option - just in case - that's good to have - as the more complex it gets it gets easier to handle if you actually 'own' all the tables - and have access to the fields etc. There is also the 'performance side' which talks about always having 'fk fields' defined as that makes things faster - I'm guessing that goes w/ index/join tables as well.

Comment: I tryied the second option an di got exactly the same Error from Sql engine.:(

Comment: what's the EF version? try EF 5 if you don't have that already. And you need to post the full model and configuration - something repeatable - you obviously have something else standing in your way there - this should work fine (it's a bit complex but all is fine). Or even better - try what I posted here 'as is', no extra fields nothing.

Comment: I have EF5 VS2012, and about the full configuration, the whole project is big, but thease two entity are just related as i explaind.

Comment: I haven't tried w/ 2012 - I'm just trying to see what else could be - I don't have any more ideas based on what you have here - this should work

Comment: The problem got solved. i commited a mistake by foregtting to add all configuration classes to OnModelCreating() of my DBcontext.After houres of chalenging with actually correct codes