# OnCascadeDelete and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a company model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Useraccount> Useraccounts { get; set; }
}
```

And a useraccount model:

```
public class Useraccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

So it's a m:n connection:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Useraccounts).WithMany(i => i.Companies)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("CompanyId")
                .MapRightKey("UseraccountId")
                .ToTable("UseraccountCompany"));            
    }
```

However an exception is thrown when initializing the database.

With

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

the initialization is working.

I'd like to keep the cascade on delete but I'm not sure how to manage it.
I also would like to keep both virtual properties so I can access the useraccounts from a company and the companies from the useraccount.

The exception btw is:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Company_Useraccounts_Target' on table 
>   'UseraccountCompany' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify 
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints.Could not create constraint.

Answer (score 0):

That should work (you probably haven't posted some relevant bits in your model - fluent configuration).

> That usually appears when you have some 'self-referencing' entities
>   (either directly or indirectly) - but I don't see that here, this is
>   typical many-to-many.

But if problems persist you can always implement the join table yourself - with more control over cascading - and that usually solves the problems (if possible).

I hate to retype :) - **here is almost the exact problem - with many-to-many manually done** (part-2).

[EF5 And cycles or multiple cascade paths, FOREIGN KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812227/ef5-and-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-foreign-key/15814567#15814567)

Take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: But there the "disable cascade on delete" is set too (.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - 'just set it to true' will that work ?